# Changing a div background color through a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello Stackoverlowers!

I need to sort out my div's and ensure that the background color of a div changes when a certain hyperlinks are closed.

My JS mark up is:

```
<script>
$("bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#blackandwhite").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#000000'},
        "slow");}
);
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="blackandwhite"> text here </div>
```

My CSS is:

```
#blackandwhite { width:100%; #FFFFFF; }
```

The link structure I am using to trigger the div to change color is like this:

```
<li><a href="#secondpagename" class="bgcolor"> link text </a></li>
```

Really cannot work out why it is not working and will appreciate any and all help! I feel like I am almost there.

All I want to do is to have the hyperlink change the div background. This hyperlink is also and will remain outside of the div. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems you need to address

1. The selector needs to look for the class `bgcolor` and hence should be `.bgcolor`
2. Probably need to prevent the default action of the hyperlink via `e.preventDefault()`. Not 100% sure about your intent here but if it's just to change the color and not jump in the page then this is likely what you want.

Try the following instead

```
$(".bgcolor").click(function(e) {
    $("#blackandwhite").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#000000'},
        "slow");
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

**EDIT**

As others have pointed out jQuery doesn't support animation out of the box.  It does support direct changes of the color though via css

```
$("#blackandwhite").css(backgroundColor: '#000000');
```

If you really want color animation though there are a number of plugins available.  For example

- http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Comment: This still isn't working? I am a little unsure on How to get it working?

It is not taking any effect?

The site is: http://www.steveatattooartist.com incase you need any visual help or a look at what could be conflicting with it :/

Thank you for your feedback, I've corrected my wrong's but still confused as hell!..

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the dot: `.bgcolor`

```
$(".bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#blackandwhite").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#000000'},
        "slow");}
);
}
```

Apart from that, I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery didn't support color animation "out of the box". Only "numeric" properties can be animated. 
You still can set you background color "directly", without an animation.

```
$(".bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#blackandwhite").css(backgroundColor: '#000000');
});
```

If you are still want to animate color, you can try this plugin: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Answer (score 0):

Your select needs to be prefixed with a dot to pick elements that have the matching class instead of matching tag name:

```
$(".bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#blackandwhite").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#000000'},
        "slow");}
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The identifier for your click function is incorrect. It should be:

```
$(".bgcolor").click(function(){
);
```

Note the dot to represent that it is searching for a class.
Also the script needs to either be placed after the element, or in `document.ready()` tags.

Answer (score 0):

First you are trying to select by css class. Correct selector syntax for this is `.<classname>`. So your selector for binding the click event should be:

```
$(".bgcolor")
```

[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)

---

Beware that jQuery **cannot animate colors** out of the box, you have to use the [Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin, or to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) which overloads the animate() method to support animating colors.

From the [.animate() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> ...**most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality** (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but **background-color cannot be**, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used)///